# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: notices

I have errors in WordPress:

> PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /home/userpro/public_html/wp-content/themes/hoon/inc/tweaks.php on
>   line 602
>
> PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/userpro/public_html/wp-content/themes/hoon/inc/tweaks.php on
>   line 602

Code:

```
/**
 * Display Future Posts
 *
 * Display future post in the events category to all users.
 */
function hoon_show_all_future_posts( $posts ) {

    global $wp_query, $wpdb;

    if ( is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0 ) {
        $events_cat = hoon_option( 'events_category' );
        $request = $wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request );
        /* Line 602 bellow  */  
        if ( post_is_in_descendant_category( $events_cat, $request[0]->ID ) || in_category( $events_cat, $request[0]->ID ) ) {
            $posts = $request;
        }
    }
    return $posts;
}
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'hoon_show_all_future_posts' );
```

Comment: This should be done using `pre_get_posts`, you shouldn't use `the_posts` to change a query like this

Answer (score 1):

If `$wp_query->post_count == 0` I cant see how `$wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request )` would return any posts. So basically

```
$request = $wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request );
```

contains nothing and `$request[0]` doesn't exist.
Ergo

```
PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

It would be interesting to know, what this could is supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The first error message is for undefined variable which you used `$request[0]` and second one is for `$request` is not a object so you cannot use as object.

I suggest you that use below code and check what you missed:

```
$request = $wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request );
print('<pre>');
print_r($request);
print('</pre>'); exit;
```

Above code shows what `$request` contains.

Let me know if you face any query regarding this OR require more help.

Comment: Thank you for attention! Where it is necessary to insert the code? I put to the end of the code and the site stopped working (white screen). An error at the end of the code, this latter function. I see this as a Problem related to the function of creating events (my theme) I do not use it, it is possible to disable this feature completely?

Comment: Place my four line code before /* Line 602 bellow  */ comment statement. Code only represent that what `$request` pull, based on that we can place new(solution) code. Do not place it any where.

Comment: No change! Error is continued! Here's how I put code in two versions. The only thing that I noticed this change in this post http://gravitation.pro/jessie-andrews

Comment: if ( is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0 ) {
  $events_cat = hoon_option( 'events_category' );
  $request = $wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request );
  
print('<pre>');
print_r($request);
print('</pre>'); exit;

Comment: if ( is_single() && $wp_query->post_count == 0 ) {
  $events_cat = hoon_option( 'events_category' );
  $request = $wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request );
 $request = $wpdb->get_results( $wp_query->request ); 
print('<pre>');
print_r($request);
print('</pre>'); exit;

Comment: How much will resolve this issue. I am ready to give you access to the server. Thank you for attention!

Comment: @Gravitation: You can share your query and server access and skype at narendra.addweb@gmail.com

Comment: Done! I send all information on your e-mail.